# Angular material data table

Tags: angular, angular-material

**Scenario:**

- I used angular material data table to show user data.
- I need to label those data with red color which will come under this
  criteria:

  - 100 minutes of outdoor games, or
  - 50 minutes of indoor games, or
  - a proportionate mix of both, e.g. 75 minutes of indoor and 120 minutes of
    outdoor games.

I am able to show whole data through json.

I need how to show those user data red who come under above criteria.

Comment: Please, add to your question some relevant code. Can't really help you without knowing what you've done.

Comment: export class UserTableComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource = new UserDataSource(this.UserService);
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name', 'gender', 'birthDate', 'height', 'weight', 'bmi'];
  constructor(private UserService:UsersService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

export class UserDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  connect(): Observable<Patient[]> {
    return this.userService.getPatient();
  }
  disconnect() { }
  constructor(private userService: usersService) {
    super();
  }
}

Comment: <div>
  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>USerId</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef = "let user">{{user.id}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef = "let user">{{user.name}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>

Comment: can you please create a demo on Stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Try to add something like this:

`[style.background-color]="isCondition ? 'green' : 'red'"`

Comment: where to add this condition

Comment: your condition is the "more than 100 minutes outdoor..." and you could add this into 

   ` <td  mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [style.background-color]="isCondition? 'green' : 'red'"> {{element.position}} </td>` for example.

the code of the table is copied from 
https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Comment: I have an array where userId are there.And then i want to show those rows as red where the user.id is included in my array.const myArr =[1,2,3];  <mat-cell *matCellDef = "let user" [class.red]="myArr.hasOwnProperty(user.id)" style="text-align:center">{{user.id}}</mat-cell>.But here its saying myArr is undefined

Comment: it would be much easier if you could add a stackblitz example here but anyway.

try to wrap your "myArr.hasOwnProperty(user.id)" call into your component.ts

component.ts:
  checkForUser(userid:number){
    return arr.hasOwnProperty(userid);
  }

in your html:

  <tr mat-row [style.background-color]="checkForUser(user.id) ? 'green' : 'white'" *matRowDef="let user; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>